# Javascript select list, show content onchange

Tags: javascript, html

The code below outputs:

> You selected Audi

How can I change this so that below the select list there is, on loading, my text about Audi which then changes to my text about BMW etc when the corresponding option is selected (using vanilla js not jQuery)?

```js
var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');

mySelect.onchange = function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="Audi">Audi
  <option value="BMW">BMW
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: You need to have an element with id `demo`

Comment: Thanks, corrected to include the demo element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [onchange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event, which gets fired as soon as a new value is selected. Also, remember to properly close tags.

**HTML**

```html
<select id="select">
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

<div id="div"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
function onValueChanged (e)
{
  document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = `You text about ${e.target.value}...`;
}

document.getElementById('select').onchange = onValueChanged;
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j57x1n0z/).

Comment: You have answered the question I asked, thank you. But my mistake - I asked "my text about Audi which then changes to my text about BMW etc" but I should have said my HTML about Audi which then changes to my HTML about BMW etc" could you adapt your answer? Or should I post a new question?

Comment: Can you be more precise? Describe the flow, so I can help. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten your code:

```js
demo.innerHTML = "You selected: " + mySelect.value;
mySelect.onchange = function() {
  demo.innerHTML = "You selected: " + this.value;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="Audi">Audi
  <option value="BMW">BMW
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```js
var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');

mySelect.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
})
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="Audi">Audi
  <option value="BMW">BMW
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the line on the beginning.

In order to maintain the DRY principle, I used an external function to update the `demo` div:

```js
function updateDemo() {
  var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `You selected: ${mySelect.value}`
}

// Just add this line:
updateDemo();

mySelect.onchange = function() {
  updateDemo();
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="Audi">Audi
  <option value="BMW">BMW
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all have a look here : 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

the option tag have a start and closing tag as well :)

Plus there is type error see below :

"message": "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null",

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample snippet

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    document.querySelector('#mySelect').addEventListener('change', function (event) {
        var x = event.target.value;
        document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
    })

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="mySelect">
      <option value="Audi">Audi </option
      ><option value="BMW">BMW </option
      ><option value="Mercedes">Mercedes </option
      ><option value="Volvo">Volvo </option>
    </select>
    <div id="demo"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```